# Return async requirejs finish callback value to outside function

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a problem, I need to wait until requirejs loads some "secondary"  dependencies and then return a computed object to my requirejs module.

Granted that I know I could pass all dependencies in the first define statement, are there alternative ways to do that?

Example:

```js
define(
    ['require', 'jquery', 'underscore'], 

    function (require, $, _) 
    {
        var fooBar = require(['foo', 'bar'], function(foo, bar) 
        {
            return new FooBar(foo, bar);
        });

        return fooBar;
    }
);
```

This module returns me a localRequire callback, instead I would want to  obtain the return value from the second require statement, so my FooBar object.

How can I achieve a similar thing?
Thanks, sorry for my English if I made mistakes, I'm Italian..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code using require as SYNC request but in browsers it is possible to use SYNC request if dependencies are defined in the same file or was loaded before calling require.
Most of the time is useful javascript minimizer is used.

```
define('foo', ['dep1', 'dep2'], function(){
    return foo;
});
define('bar', ['dep1', 'dep2'], function(){
    return bar;
});

define(
    ['require', 'jquery', 'underscore'], 

    function (require, $, _) 
    {
        var foo = require('foo');
        var bar = require('bar');
        return new FooBar(foo, bar);
    }
);
```

Other solution is using Promises to promise you will return new object:

```
define(
    ['require', 'jquery', 'underscore'], 

    function (require, $, _) 
    {
        var promise = new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
            require(['foo', 'bar'], function(foo, bar) 
            {
                fulfill(new FooBar(foo, bar));
            });
        });

        return promise;
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know I could define multiple dependencies at once, and that previous loaded dependencies  were available for reuse in later loaded modules! I am new in requirejs !

Answer (score 0):

```
define(function (require) { 
   var $ = require('jquery');
   var _ = require('underscore');
   var foo = require('foo');
   var bar  = require('bar');
  return new FooBar(foo, bar);   
});
```

Comment: I already knew the common-js method, but for some reasons I needed to avoid that method. Thanks anyway!